# Pythonic way of constructing an array based on boolean arguments?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

I was just wondering how would a pythonic code look like to tackle this problem:

Suppose you have a function:

```
def do_stuff(a=True, b=True, c=True, d=True):
```

And inside that function you want to construct corresponding objects:

```
elements = []
if a:
    elements.append(A())
if b:
    elements.append(B())
if c:
    elements.append(C())
if d:
    elements.append(D())
```

Are there any more beautiful ways of writing this code? If not maybe optional parameters is not "the way to go"?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want the user to pass in the `elements`list?

Comment: Definitely possible. Although its just a philosophical and aesthetic problem. Other approaches are welcome!

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus Question is, what is A, B, C, and D?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. But the intention was that i construct new objects here. A B C and D are classes. But would it change something if I was about to say A B C and D are methods ?

Comment: It seems a bit unusual for these separate arguments to control the presence of elements of the same list. If these elements are homogeneous enough that they're handled in the same list, I would expect a more unified form of input than as separate arguments; alternatively, with `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` all being separate classes, it may not make sense to stuff all the objects in the same list.

Comment: How are you calling `do_stuff`?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any more beautiful ways of writing this code?

To be honest, in my opinion **no**. You could make a clever hack and use that, but the purpose of writing good code is to make it clear and readable, and easily understandable. All of which I don't think any other method would qualify as being, except what you have now.

Sure it looks pretty verbose, but it's better to have a verbosity rather than unnecessary complexity. Sometimes the obvious way is the most idiomatic, robust, clean, and "pythonic" solution. In this case, I think it's best to do KISS.

However, this also depends on how you pass your arguments to your function. What you're doing now seems a bit strange. It would probably be much more natural to pass in a list, or a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
elements = [X() for x, X in ((a, A), (b, B), (c, C), (d, D)) if x]
```

Your whole approach looks rather strange, though. Probably you shouldn't have those arguments like that. But without knowing more about what you actually need...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

def do_stuff(a=True, b=True, c=True, d=True):
    elements = [val() for val in compress([A, B, C, D], [a,b,c,d])]
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. There are better approaches to solve that. I updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly clean way (and extensible) way of doing it:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass
class D: pass

def do_stuff(a=True, b=True, c=True, d=True):
    classes, args = (A, B, C, D), (a, b, c, d)
    elements = [classes[i]() for (i, arg) in enumerate(args) if arg]
    # Show results.
    print(list('class {} obj'.format(element.__class__.__name__) for element in elements))

do_stuff(1,1,1,1)  # -> ['class A obj', 'class B obj', 'class C obj', 'class D obj']
do_stuff(0,1,1,0)  # -> ['class B obj', 'class C obj']
do_stuff()         # -> ['class A obj', 'class B obj', 'class C obj', 'class D obj']
do_stuff(0,0)      # -> ['class C obj', 'class D obj']
do_stuff(b=False)  # -> ['class A obj', 'class C obj', 'class D obj']
```

Note I use `0` and `1` in place of `False` and `True` because Python will treat them the same (it considers the "truthiness" of non-boolean values by whether or not they're `0` or empty containers, depending on their type).

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of objects that need to call according to a condition, the repetition of the `if` statements is something to avoid:

```
objs = {True:A, True:B, True:C ,...}

def do_stuff(objs):
    return [obj() for key, obj in objs.items() if key]
```

Irrespective of what those callable objects do now, you just call them and whatever they return is collected and held inside the list returned by `do_stuff`. Future expansion is easier now, just remove the unwanted objects from `objs` dictionary or set their keys to `False` or really to any object whose boolean value is `False`.